# Finding $\sin(x+y)$ if $3\sin x+4\cos y=5$ and $4\sin y+3 \cos x=2$

Tags: trigonometry

> Suppose that $x$ and $y$ satisfy the equations
> $$\begin{align}
> 3\sin x+4\cos y &=5 \\
> 4\sin y+3 \cos x &=2
> \end{align}$$
> What is the value of $\sin(x+y)$?

I'm quite rusty at trigonometry, and this practice question confused me so much. Can someone give me a detailed explanation on how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

We want $ \sin(x+y) = \sin x \cos y + \cos x \sin y$.

Note that the first equation has a linear combination of $ \sin x $ & $\cos y$ ... but we want their product ... so square it !

Is this enough of a hint ?

> $ ( 3 \sin x + 4 \cos y )^2 + ( 4 \sin y + 3 \cos x )^2 = 5^2+2^2 \\ 9(  \sin^2 x +  \cos^2 x ) + 24(\sin x \cos y + \cos x \sin y) +16 ( \sin^2 y +  \cos^2 y ) = 5^2+2^2 \\ \sin(x+y) =\color{red}{\frac{1}{6}}$.

Answer (score 2):

Square the equations then add them to get $\sin x\cos y+\cos x\sin y=1/6$.